# Reporting Services : Changing a specific cells background color

Tags: reporting-services

Does anyone know how to change the background color of a single cell, to a color specified by the hex number in SSRS? There are multiple different hex numbers in the database, for multiple different records and each color corresponds to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- Your hex value is 6 digits prefixed by a `#`
- The column containing the background color you want to apply is called `BGColor`

Here is what you can do:

1. Select all the cells you want to format
2. In the Properties window (press <kbd>F4</kbd> if not shown), under `Fill`, locate the `BackgroundColor` property
3. Change it to the following expression: `=Fields!BGColor.Value`

**Note**
If your hex value is not in the required format, you have 2 options:

- Update the query accordingly
- Change the expression, you could use Custom Code or just some string operation functions like `Right` or `Left` for example

Answer (score 1):

Within each cell is a `Color` property that you could set to the column value. The properties window can be found in the View tab at the top.